# How do I get c# to get all URLs from a website and put them into a list

Tags: c#, .net, list

So I am trying to get my C# code to pick a random image from a website but I don't know how to get the program to get the image URL

I have tried the code on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418716/how-can-i-get-a-liststring-of-images-from-a-website-link#_=_), but I can seem to get it to work

```
private List<string> retrieveImages()
{
  List<string> imgList = new List<string>();
  HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
  doc.Load("file.htm"); //or whatever HTML file you have
  HtmlNodeCollection imgs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src]");
  if (imgs == null) return new List<string>();

  foreach (HtmlNode img in imgs)
  {
   if (img.Attributes["src"] == null)
      continue;
   HtmlAttribute src = img.Attributes["src"];

   imgList.Add(src.Value);
   //Do something with src.Value such as Get the image and save it locally
   // Image img = GetImage(src.Value)
   // img.Save(aLocalFilePath);
  }
return imgList;
}

private Image GetImage(string url)
{
    System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);

    System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    System.IO.Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(responseStream);

    responseStream.Dispose();

    return bmp;
}
```

Program closes with no error

Comment: `Program closes with no error` Did you debug through it, line by line? On each line ask yourself 'what do I expect this line of code to do?' At some point, you will reach a line of code where what you **expected** to happen didn't happen. That is where you should start investigating. _Also, consider changing your profile pic. It looks odd._

Comment: Unless we can copy and paste the code into a console app and it compiles and runs **without alteration**, then we really can't help much, since you haven't provided a [mcve].